# Duplicate IP in Apache access log behind nginx proxy

Tags: nginx, apache-2.4, x-forwarded-for

I've recently inherited an infrastructure where all the users go through an AWS ELB -> nginx proxy -> AWS ELB -> Apache. The problem I'm seeing is that the client's IP is showing twice in Apache, a line similar to this:

`"x.x.x.x, x.x.x.x" - - [26/Oct/2016:18:59:10 +0000] "GET /....`

nginx's access log for this virtual host is fine and dandy:

`x.x.x.x - - [26/Oct/2016:18:59:10 +0000] "GET /`

The problem is that I'm not really sure how to debug where this gets lost. I assume it's either the headers nginx is sending or something weird in Apache, although I suspect it is the X-Forwarded-For headers that nginx is passing. Here's the relevant virtual host configuration for an affected domain:

`location / {
        if ($xxx-example-com-maintenance) {
            return 503;
        }
        if ($http_origin ~* (https?://xxx\.example\.com)) {
            add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        }
        proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
        proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_pass $upstream;`

Now, Apache's log format looks like this:

`LogFormat "\"%{X-Forwarded-For}i\" %l %u %t \"%r\" %>s %b \"%{Referer}i\" \"%{User-agent}i\" SESSION-%{frontend}C %h" forwarded`

The latter was copied from the previous web stack and worked just fine. Kinda stuck here because it all looks good from my perspective. I did find [nginx real_ip_header and X-Forwarded-For seems wrong](https://serverfault.com/questions/314574/nginx-real-ip-header-and-x-forwarded-for-seems-wrong) however I'm running nginx 1.10. Apache version is 2.4.23. Any insights on how to troubleshoot this further would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out that X-Forwarded-For header is meant to behave like that and the solution was to use a different header that the ELB wasn't using - in my case X-Real-IP. I'm now able to see a single IP in the logs.